# How to get AssetManager from a library project

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-assetmanager

I am trying to get `AssetManager` form a class in an Android library project, but I am getting the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
```

This is how I call it:

```
public class RevPluginLoader extends AppCompatActivity {

    private List<String> copyPlugins() {
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();  // This is where it all fails
    }
}
```

How can I get the `AssetManager`?

Comment: did you forget to add context ??  context.getAsset() ....,

Comment: Where you added the assets folder..? in your lib module or in the main module..? try to add it in main module and check.

Comment: I'm adding it in the lib module @MuthukrishnanRajendran

Comment: Add it in Main Module and check.

Comment: How can I go about adding it in the lib module @MuthukrishnanRajendran

Comment: Unfortunately, You cant add in lib module, check my answer below.

Comment: Hi @Program-Me-Rev Please add more details in question,like RevPluginLoader in Library/in normal project.You project structure screen shot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can't add assets folder in lib module

> Library modules cannot include raw assets The tools do not support the
>   use of raw asset files (saved in the assets/ directory) in a library
>   module. Any asset resources used by an app must be stored in the
>   assets/ directory of the app module itself.

For More details, you can [refer here](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html#Considerations)

Comment: I am using assets in lib folder :), including layout

Comment: **layout** you can use but asserts you can't as per doc please refer the link which I provided in my answer. If you are using in different way of adding assets in your lib, share us the ideas, so that other people can get help.

Comment: on your link "Additionally, an AAR file may include one or more of the following optional entries: assets" . Lol

Answer (score 1):

I think you have  a `onCreateView`

```
public class RevPluginLoader extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Context mContext = null; //declare a context here
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mContext  = this; //assign class object to context
    }

    private List<String> copyPlugins() {
        AssetManager assetManager = mContext.getAssets(); //use context here
    }
}
```

**Check commented lines**

This may solve your problem

Comment: RevPluginLoader have context reference all over the class other than the static method.

Comment: but the error showing getresourse called on a null object